# Class diagrams created through objectaid in eclipse disappeared

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, class-diagram, objectaid

I am using eclipse plugin ObjectAid for creating class diagrams from my classes. After creating about 4 diagrams, the next day when I tried to open the class diagrams, I see that three out of the four diagrams are empty with an yellow exclamation icon near the ones which are empty.

Any idea why this has happened? Is there any way to retrieve the class diagrams?

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me also, one or more (even 5) restarts of Eclipse finally helped. Try some black magic, like close the diagram, then restart Eclipse, then open the diagram again and repeat until the diagram appears.

Answer (score 0):

Open up Window > Show View > Model Explorer > Open your project > ** Diagram Class Diagram.